# Custom view with horizontalScrollview in RecyclerView match_parent not working

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

[image]I have a `RecyclerView` that includes my custom view.
My custom view not get all the width even so I configure it as `match_parent.`
what i want is that the horizontal scroll view will take all screen, and also the card will take screen width (so the yelow part will stay outside at beginning)

I've tried to use `LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_home_screen_card, (ViewGroup) this, false),` but didn't work

Also I've tried to set width programmatically, but I'm seeing the wrong size for few milliseconds before it's change and its look ugly.

The weird thing is that when i'm taking out the horizontal scroll view, the view take all place.

attached the layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <merge
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         android:scrollbars="none">

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/view_home_card_and_button_layout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">


             <ImageView
                 android:layout_width="100dp"
                 android:layout_height="150dp"
                 android:background="@color/amber_200" />

             <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                 android:id="@+id/cardView"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_unit"
                 app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/8dp">


             </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


         </LinearLayout>

     </HorizontalScrollView>


 </merge>
```

any more ideas?

Comment: please share your custom layout code

Comment: @RahulChokshi i've edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Is your recyclerview have match_parent width? If no then make it.

Comment: The recycle view is match parent and take all screen size

Comment: can you share your custom layout

Comment: try to remove layout_margin from cardview and background color from imageview

Comment: Tried that, Didnt help

Comment: can you post a screenshot of expected and actual output for that layout

Comment: attached the photo